# Чтение и обработка CSV в многопоточном режиме

Tags: java, многопоточность

Я хочу считать `CSV` файл с большим количеством строк и обработать эти строки в многопоточном режиме. Делаю так:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CsvReaderApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CsvReaderApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(args[0]);
    String thisLine;
    int count = 0;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1000);

    while ((thisLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
        if (count > 150) count = 0;
        pool.submit(new MyTask(thisLine));
        count++;
    }

    pool.shutdown();
}
}

class MyTask implements  Runnable {

private String line;
private static int countLine = 0;

public MyTask(String line) {
    this.line = line;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    countLine ++;
    System.out.println("Line: " + line + " countLine: " + countLine);
//бизнес логика
}
}
```

В итоге получается так, что в методе `run` строки выводятся не в порядке, в котором они идут в файле, а в разнобой. Можно ли как-то обработать строки в том порядке, в котором они идут в исходном файле или вообще есть более эффективный способ?

Comment: Многопоточность == асинхронность. Если вы хотите работать в несколько потоков, но ,чтобы все было по порядку, то вы поставите все потоки в очередь, т.е. потеряете все плюсы многопоточности, но получите все минусы (время на создание потоков и их поддержку)

Comment: @Виктор, я вас понял. В таком случае получается, что например, один поток считал какую-то строку, обработал ее, а затем любой другой поток может взять эту же строку и делать тоже самое с ней. Можно ли этого как-то избежать, что если строка была обработана, другой поток ее не трогал?

Comment: Потоки не берут строки. В вашем примере вы отправляете строку потоку, так что если не отправите 1 строку 2 раза, то дублироваться она не будет. Главный вопрос, зачем вам тут многопоточность?

Comment: @Виктор, дело в том, что у меня файл, содержащий около 10 млн. строк. Потоками я хотел бы как-то укорить обработку этих строк. Возможно я в чем-то не прав.

Comment: вопрос в том, зачем вам по итогу это. Если вам нужен вывод в консоль в определенном порядке, то придется синхронизировать потоки, т.е. использовать много потоков, но выстроить их в очередь. Тогда вы получаете все затраты на многопоточность, но в итоге пользуетесь каждым потоком по отдельности. Вы спрятали бизнес логику, но сейчас именно в ней суть, там ответ "зачем вам это".

Comment: @Виктор, мне нужно, считать файл, содержащий около 10 млн. строк, посчитать от каждой строки хэш, и на выходе сформировать такой же csv файл, содержащий эту же строку + ее хэш. Хотелось бы это сделать максимально быстро, насколько это возможно. В этом вся суть

Comment: суть в том что на создание потока уходит слишком много времени и вы теряете его капитально, так что никакого максимально быстро у вас не получится.